# clustering large file to 3 group with levenahtein

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, cluster-computing, k-means

Hi I have a small file and large file, 
the code here doesnt even work for the large file, only the small file, so how can I read and do actions on the large file? when I read and try to cluster in one loop it doesnt work because every iteration is only on line.
here is the issue with the small file:
file of lines and I need to cluster them into 3 groups.
I've tried affinity propagation but it doesnt get group size parameter, it give me 4 groups, while the 4th group has only one word that very close to another group:

```
0
 - *Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.
:* Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.

1
 - *BOZEMAN Enterprises
:* BBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD
, BOZEMAN Ent.
, BOZEMAN Enterprises
, BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
, BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD
, Bozeman Enterprises

2
 - *PC Adelman
:* John Smith
, Michele LTD
, Nadelman, Jr
, PC Adelman

3
 - *Gramkai, Inc.
:* Gramkai Books
, Gramkai, Inc.
, Gramkat Estates, Inc., Gramkat, Inc.
```

then I tried K-MEANS but the result :

```
0
 - *Gramkai Books
, Gramkai, Inc.
, Gramkat Estates, Inc., Gramkat, Inc.
:*
1
 - *BBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD
, BOZEMAN Enterprises
, BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES
, BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD
, Bozeman Enterprises
, Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.
:*
2
 - *BOZEMAN Ent.
, John Smith
, Michele LTD
, Nadelman, Jr
, PC Adelman
:*
```

as you can see BOZEMAN Ent. is in group 2 instead of group 1.

my question is:is there a way to do a better clustring? and is there a cluster_center in K-MEANS ?

the code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.cluster
import distance

f = open("names.txt", "r")
words = f.readlines()
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])
affprop = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    print(cluster_id)
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:*" % ( cluster_str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Clustering of given text names (enterprises) can be improved in several ways.

1. Introduce some text cleaning and domain knowledge, removing  for example dots , common enterprise stopwords, and lowering characters:

```
words = [re.sub(r"(,|\.|ltd|l\.t\.d|inc|estates|enterprises|ent|estatys)","", w.lower()).strip() for w in words]
```

2. Use "normalized" version of `distance.levenshtein` so distances can be meaningfully compared, example:

```
distance.nlevenshtein("abc", "acd", method=1)  # shortest alignment
distance.nlevenshtein("abc", "acd", method=2)  # longest alignment
```

3. Try another measures of distances: `sorensen` or `jaccard` which are already normalized.

Below complete code example:

```
words = \
["Gramkai Books",
"Gramkai, Inc.",
"Gramkat Estates, Inc.",
"Gramkat, Inc.",
"BBAZEMAX ESTATES, LTD",
"BOZEMAN Enterprises",
"BOZERMAN ENTERPRISES",
"BRAZEMAX ESTATYS, LTD",
"Bozeman Enterprises",
"Bras5emax Estates, L.T.D.",
"BOZEMAN Ent.",
"John Smith",
"Michele LTD",
"Nadelman, Jr",
"PC Adelman"]

import re
import sklearn
from sklearn import cluster
words = [re.sub(r"(,|\.|ltd|l\.t\.d|inc|estates|enterprises|ent|estatys)","", w.lower()).strip() for w in words]
words = np.asarray(words) #So that indexing with a list will work
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.nlevenshtein(w1,w2,method = 1) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])
affprop = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3)
affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
for cluster_id in np.unique(affprop.labels_):
    print(cluster_id)
    cluster = np.unique(words[np.nonzero(affprop.labels_==cluster_id)])
    cluster_str = ", ".join(cluster)
    print(" - *%s:*" % ( cluster_str))
```

Result:

```
0
 - *john smith, michele, nadelman jr, pc adelman:*
1
 - *bbazemax, bozeman, bozerman, bras5emax, brazemax:*
2
 - *gramkai, gramkai books, gramkat:*
```

Finally You may need to join changed names with original names.